# Как я могу разбить строку по регулярному выражению?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, boost, строки, c++, format

Есть строки формата

```
     tom 18 Moscow
     anna 21
     kate is old
     yura lives in London
```

Как я могу разбить с помощью регулярных выражений C++ (boost) каждую из строк на первое слово и остальные?
Я помню, что в перле есть что-то вроде (\w+)(\s+)(\w+) а дальше можно получить значения каждой из скобок в формате $1, $2, $3.  А вот как я могу проделать это на boost?
Пробовал разбивать строку через istringstream. Но в этом случаи получается vector n-ого размера, где n-число слов. А нужно, чтобы было 2 части, т.к затем вторая часть строки будет париться по тому же принципу, что и начальная строка, но только, например, по другому разделителю (соответственно нужно будет объединять myvector.at(1)..myvector.at(myvector.size()-1) и начитать все сначала. А также нужно каждый раз проверять размер myvector, чтобы не было выхода за диапазон). С учетом того, что вариантов формата строки может быть много, не удобно для каждого варианта прописывать кучу кода, гораздо проще прописать для каждого варианта свой regexp.
Подскажите, как я могу проделать похожее на перл (или не похожее) получения слов со строки на С++? спасибо
P.S или может вы знаете другой способ, как можно решить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение в лоб:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
std::string get_head(std::string s) {
    size_t n = s.find(' ');
    return s.substr(0, n);
}

std::string get_tail(std::string s) {
    size_t n = s.find(' ');
    return s.substr(n+1, s.length());
}
int main() {
    std::string s = "test qwerty asdf";
    std::cout << get_head(s) << std::endl << get_tail(s) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

можно ещё один параметр добавить для разделителя. Но чувствую, что Вам в основном нужна будет только функция `get_head`.

В бусте есть много. Есть [регулярки](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/captures_example.cpp) (хотя они есть и в последнем стандарте и многие компиляторы поддерживают их с коробки), есть специальная библиотека для написания парсеров - [Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) + [примеры с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/86899/).

Comment: @KoVadim, наверное стоит добавить, что перед первым словом не должно быть пробелов, да и остальные слова (если `get_head()`, `get_tail()` использовать в цикле) должны разделяться ровно одним пробелом.

Answer (score 0):

В boost'е не шарю, но регулярку предложу http://regex101.com/r/uR4lZ3

Comment: похоже, что с регулярками тоже:)

Comment: @KoVadim, это почему же, первое же слово в каждой строке матчит вроде верно???

Comment: Понял! Сорри, не внимательно читал вопрос: http://regex101.com/r/gF4mB0

Comment: Автор вопроса пишет, что у него первое "слово" отделятся пробелом. То есть, в первом "слове" может быть минус. А он под \w уже не попадает. Я специально пишу "слово" в кавычках, что бы было понятно, что это не просто слово, а набор любых символов до разделителя.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно выбрать несколько первых слов из строк `char[]` (или `char *`) можете  использовать

```
// strtos.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define SPACES " \t\n\r\f\v"
int
strtowv (const char *src, char **tail, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, tail);
  char **x;
  int n = 0;

  while (x = va_arg(ap, char **)) {
    if (!*(src += strspn(src, SPACES)))
      break;
    const char *s = src;
    src += strcspn(src, SPACES);
    *x = strndup(s, src - s);
    n++;
  }
  if (tail)
    *tail = (char *)src;
  va_end(ap);

  return n;
}

int
strtowa (const char *src, char **arr, int n, char **tail)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (*(src += strspn(src, SPACES)) && i < n) {
    const char *s = src;
    src += strcspn(src, SPACES);
    arr[i++] = strndup(s, src - s);
    if (i == n)
      break;
  }
  if (tail)
    *tail = (char *)src;

  return i;
}
```

как в С++, так и в  Си.

`strtowv` похожа на `sscanf()` и принимает переменное число параметров типа `char **` для результата своей работы. Этот список надо завершать нулем (как в `execl()`).

`strtowa` возвращает результат разбора в массиве `char *[]` размер которого ей передается.

Обе функции возвращают количество успешно выделенных слов, и в своих аргументах (кроме аргумента tail) копию слов в динамической памяти. (Освобождать надо вызовом free()).

В tail возвращается адрес символа где прекратился разбор первого аргумента.

Пример для Вашего вопроса:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:t2info$ gcc tss.c strtos.o
avp@avp-ubu1:t2info$ ./a.out
strtowa:  <wrd1  wrd2 222>
n = 1 [wrd1] tail: [  wrd2 222]
strtowv: <wrd1  wrd2 222>
n = 1 [wrd1] tail: [  wrd2 222]
avp@avp-ubu1:t2info$ cat tss.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int strtowa (const char *src, char **arr, int n, char **tail);
int strtowv (const char *src, char **tail, ...);

int
main ()
{
  int n;
  char *w = 0, *tail;
  const char *tst = "wrd1  wrd2 222";

  printf ("strtowa:  <%s>\n", tst);
  n = strtowa(tst, &w, 1, &tail);
  printf("n = %d [%s] tail: [%s]\n", n, n > 0 ? w : "", tail);
  free(w);

  printf ("strtowv: <%s>\n", tst);
  n = strtowv(tst, &tail, &w, 0);
  printf("n = %d [%s] tail: [%s]\n", 
         n, n > 0 ? w : "", tail);
}

avp@avp-ubu1:t2info$
```